# Engraved text (on a cylinder). The printer wasnt able to display the font style correctly,

Tags: print-quality, elegoo-mars

Printer: Elegoo Mars 3 LCD Resin printer

The letter height is about 3 mm.

I engraved a word (text) on the side of a cylinder (which is about 14 mm in diameter and 4 mm in height).  I am not sure about the exact depth of the engraving (but should be about 0.5 mm but that's not important).

The text is easily readable and, at first glance, appears to have come out perfectly.
On second sight, however, the problem becomes obvious: The 3D printer didn't print the style of the font correctly (it's less **bold** than the font style chosen for the text and that's visible in Blender and Chitubox files).

Is that just what I have to accept or is there any way to improve on the result?

Comment: It strikes me that the amount of bolding is less important than legibility. Also, it's amusing that the depth of the engraving is 0.5mm "or whatever" but that it's not bold enough...

Answer (score 1):

You could try making the text in the 3D model more bold than you want it, then if the printer prints it less bold, it will come out with the desired boldness.

Answer (score 1):

## Printers know not of Fonts

All the 3D printer knows are movement commands. The slicer is turning the model into movement commands. The design suit defines the model.

So if your slicer is not printing the model as you envision it, the problem is not with the printer, it is with the model. You should alter the surfaces in the model.